# A coarea formula when proving maximum principles for strong solutions in Chapter9 in Gilbarg-Trudinger's book

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

**strong text**
In GT's book(1998 Edition) Chapter9 P223,
Let $g$ be a nonnegative, locally integrable function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u\in C^2(\Omega)\bigcap C^0(\bar\Omega)$.

How to prove

$\int_{Du(\Omega)}{g(p)}dp\le \int_{\Gamma^{+}}{g(Du)|\det D^2u|}dx$?

where $\Gamma^{+}=\{y\in\Omega|u(x)\le u(y)+ Du(y)\cdot(x-y), for \forall x\in \Omega\}$

Answer (score 2):

More precisely it is the area formula, see 3.7 of Frank Morgan, *Geometric Measure Theory* for a sketch of the proof, or 3.2.3 of Federer, *Geometric Measure Theory* for a complete proof.

Comment: I know that  $\int_{(Du-\varepsilon I)(\Omega)}{g(p)}dp= \int_{\Gamma^{+}}{g(Du-\varepsilon I)|\det (D^2u-\varepsilon I)|}dx$. But I don't know how to use approximation.

Comment: I'm not sure what approximation you're talking about. Presumably there's no such approximation in Gilbarg-Trudinger.